# Wordpress Bricks Builder Dynamically Fill Select Options

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, datetime

Bricks builder for Wordpress has an option to echo a function as dynamic content for form fields.

I need to offer users a choice of dates from the next 6 days.

I have a select field and the following function:

```
function generate_date_options() {
    $date_options = array();

    // Generate dates for the next six days
    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$i days"));
        $formatted_date = date('F j, Y', strtotime("+$i days"));
        $date_options[$formatted_date] = $formatted_date;
    }

    return $date_options;
}
```

This function returns a list of the next 6 dates.

I want each date to be an option in the select field. But instead they are all listed on a single line separated by comas as the single select option.

The function is defined in a child theme function.php and can be called using `{echo: generate_date_options()}`.

The Date/Time picker would be ideal but does not allow narrowing of the range of dates available to just the next 6 days.

Any ideas on this method or an alternative gratefully received.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the file where `generate_date_options` is called? And this is slightly off-topic, but it immediately caught my eye: you're calling `strtotime(...)` twice, which is bound to break around midnight. Unlikely as it is, it will result in the user selecting one date and actually entering another one.

Comment: The site isn't live yet so I can't link. I've found a plugin I can use to handle date options - but I'm still interested in resolving this in case the plugin option falls through.

Comment: If all you really need to do is fill in five consecutive dates into a `<select>`, you (probably) shouldn't need a plugin for that for sure. I'll be happy to provide more help, but I need to see how the function is used within the template.